# Why can't I access my WCF web service with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, web-services, httprequest

I'm new at AJAX and I'm trying to access a WCF web service the following way:

```
$(function () {
    $('#formNew').submit(function () {
        var datos = {
            "Nombre": $('#nombre').val(),
            "ApellidoP": $('#appP').val(),
            "ApellidoM": $('#appM').val(),
            "UserName": $('#username').val(),
            "Password": $('#password').val(),
        };
        var args = "Data=" + JSON.stringify(datos);
        var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:81/SismosService.svc/usuario/new?' + args;
        alert(url);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Exito " + JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error " + JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I fill the form and click the submit button, I get the following error on Firebug:

N

```
S_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: prompt aborted by user
[Break On This Error]   

throw Components.Exception("prompt aborted by user", Cr.NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)
```

My web service is defined as follows:

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/usuario/new?Data={data}",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    ResponseObject<Usuarios> NewUsuario(string data);
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it the way I'm sending the parameters? Is is the way I'm trying to access the web service? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The  **JSON.stringify(data)** use is to convert a javascript object to json representation.

I think that in the success\error functions you need to go the other way:

```
 success: function (data) {
                            alert("Exito " + JSON.parse(data));
                          },
 error:   function (data) {
                            alert("Error " + JSON.parse(data));
                          }
```

(when using JSON.parse, JSON.stringify - make sure you included the json2.min.js in your project)

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem, the call to the web service isn't made, I copy-pasted my url variable on a tab and it does access to the endpoint, I don't know why isn't accessing to the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the following configuration to enable ajax calls to my WCF services:

1) First I create a JSON endpoint behaviour in Web.config and associate my service to it:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WebHttpJson">
        <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped"
                 defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="MyApp.LoginService">
      <endpoint address=""
                behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpJson"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                contract="MyApp.LoginService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

2) Then I can simply define my WCF service like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class LoginService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public void SignIn(string email, string pswd)
    {
        // Check credentials and create session cookie
    }
}
```

3) And finally make jQuery ajax calls like showed below:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: serviceUrl + '/SignIn',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        email: 'john.doe@abc.com', 
        pswd: 'qwerty'
    }),
    success: function () { alert('success!'); },
    error: function () { alert('error!'); }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why I should replace the WebGet attribute with the OperationContract attribute, it seems to have less ways to configurate each endpoint. But still, it didn't work.
I made my web.config look like [this](http://pastebin.com/dTnNJDj6), [this](http://pastebin.com/8gZ2CG5z) is how my method for adding new users is defined and [this](http://pastebin.com/5pnpqjma) is how my javascript function to make the call looks like. I think I'm not explaining myself clearly, for some reason I can't get to make a call to the endpoint through ajax, I'm really confused, I'm new at it.

Comment: 1) You must use the [OperationContract Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.aspx) to indicate which methods are part of your WCF service; 2) Your Web.Config seems fine, and if your app compiles without errors it probably is; 3) Remove all attributes you are currently using in your C# method, some of them are conflicting with the Web.Config; 4) The **url** in your ajax call is wrong, it should end with your method name *NewUsuario*, but it is ending with *new*; 5) Change your *args* string to start with **data=** (case sensitive)

Comment: the Uri template attribute let's me specify the url I'm accessing, that's why I was accessing /usuario/new instead of NewUsuario, it works if I access to it through a browser. Anyway I removed all the WebGet and tried to access to 127.0.0.1:81/SismosService.svc/GetUsuarios but it didn't work, it said Method not Allowed

Comment: as of now I'm getting this error {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"} and according to [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2011/11/17/html5-and-cross-origin-resource-sharing-call.aspx) it's because of CORS issues, but I already added CORS compability on my web.config, I don't understand why I can't access to the endpoints in charge of inserting, updating or deleting

Comment: How are you accessing the web page that has the ajax call? If you are accessing it like this "http://localhost/myapp/mypage.aspx" then your web service should use "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1". The other issue is that it seems you're using a different port at your WCF endpoint, and I'm not sure browsers will allow that. Why are you defining another name to your method, using a custom port and using GET instead of POST anyway?

Comment: I want to be able to access the web service from a different domain, so I'm allowing CORS compability, I'm defining a different name for the method just for the usual convention of having an url like this website.com/controller/action and it being easier for me to send the parameters using GET rather than POST, I'm not really experienced in web developing so I'm using what it works best for me.