# Format of JSON message for WCF Service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I have a wcf service. I need to save users with it and make a response. This is my method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SaveUsersCode", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    Response SaveUsers(UserCode code);
```

UserCode class just have two string properties. I'm using Google Postman for checking. I've tried everything and always get an error "The server encountered an error processing the request".

What is the correct format of sending JSON messages?

Comment: `I've tried everything` If we knew what you had tried, we could give better answers.

Comment: I've tried {"companyName":"cocaCola","imsi":"3324","msisdn":"21331"}, {companyName:"cocaCola","imsi":3324,msisdn:"21331"}, '{"companyName":"cocaCola","imsi":"3324","msisdn":"21331"}',{"UserCode":[{"companyName":"cocaCola","imsi":"3324","msisdn":"21331"}]}

Comment: Take a look at this: [Why can't I access my WCF web service with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328466/why-cant-i-access-my-wcf-web-service-with-javascript/14328818#14328818)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flipper i wrote a server code using your template

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MyServer
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            WebServiceHost ws = new WebServiceHost(this.GetType(), new Uri("http://0.0.0.0/Test"));
            ws.Open();
        });
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SaveUsersCode", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string SaveUsers(UserCode code)
    {
        return "GOT: " + code.companyName + "," + code.imsi;
    }

    public class UserCode
    {
        public string companyName;
        public string imsi;
    }
}
```

and called it as

```
//Start server
var m = new MyServer();
m.Start();
Task.Delay(1000);

//Call server method
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    var obj = new { companyName = "cocaCola",imsi="3324" };
    string response = wc.UploadString("http://localhost/Test/SaveUsersCode", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj));
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

ta-da, it Works

Comment: Not working for me, I'm still getting bad syntax error at json - really don't know what now