# ASP.NET web service - How to change payload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

Is it possible to change a payload of a Ajax call to an ASP.NET web service?

I have a class like following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I pass this to a client, I encrypt the ID into an alphanumeric string for security.
So, a client sends over a JSON object like following back to the server:

```
Foo = {
    ID: "Some alphanumeric string",
    Name: "John Doe"
}
```

Thus, I cannot create a web service that receives a User object, because the JSON object cannot be casted into a User object.

Is there a way to intercept the AJAX call and decrypt the ID before it hits the web service so that the casting can be done properly?

I have tried creating a [custom HTTP module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but it allows me only to read the payload, not to change it.
Aspect oriented programming like PostSharp will not work because casting happens before my web service is called.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, good tip. As an aside, one thing I've always found laughable is that `REST` is just the old `ASMX` technology **renamed.** Much like Microsoft started the *desktop* revolution, then realized it was a good idea to host these applications, but couldn't let people know IBM had been doing it for decades that way so they called it **the cloud.** :D

Comment: REST is not related to the ASMX technology. ASMX uses SOAP. REST is sort of the opposite of SOAP.

Comment: In the following link you can find some sample code on how to perform Ajax calls using WCF: [Why can't I access my WCF web service with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328466/why-cant-i-access-my-wcf-web-service-with-javascript/14328818#14328818). Also take a look at WCF [Message Inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx), they allow you to alter incoming messages before they are processed by your WCF service.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion about WCF. However, this is just one web service of a big web app. I cannot afford migrating the whole app to WCF. Is there anyway to do this within ASMX technology?