# Endpoint address 404 trying to create a WCF service to handle jQuery.ajax requests

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, iis, knockout.js

I'm trying to set up a WCF service to handle AJAX requests using the jQuery `$.ajax` method. I'm having trouble getting my service correctly hosted by IIS.
I've been looking through [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx) and some [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery) articles to try and find out why I'm getting a 404 error whenever I try to type the endpoint in my browser.

*I think my problem is in the actual hosting and attributes I'm trying to apply to my service interface or implementing class. I have never had to set up a web.config but it seems pretty straightforward, I just don't know what all I need to be able to make AJAX calls.*

I can't get any metadata to show up when I try to point my browser to the service endpoint. I'm currently trying any combination of

```
"http://localhost/Knockout/AjaxDataService.svc/TestAjaxCall"
"/Knockout/AjaxDataService.svc/TestAjaxCall"
"/AjaxDataService.svc/TestAjaxCall"
"AjaxDataService.svc/TestAjaxCall"
```

And none of them are working. I get a 404 error message in Chrome

I thought I would post my code so far while I struggle through looking for the answer on my own, in case someone might be able to easily see why I'm failing with this...

**edit:** I might be missing some elements in the web.config that are needed to host a WCF service in IIS, but I can't find a consistent consensus on the content needed to expose the endpoint to AJAX calls. It seems like every single article I try to read through to help me with this problem has differences in the way the interface, implementing class and web.config are set up.

**edit:** Maybe my folder hierarchy would help with this?
I have `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Knockout` as the directory for my application in IIS. Within that folder I have these items

```
/App_Code
    AjaxDataService.svc.cs
/jQuery
    jquery-1.10.0.min.js
/ViewModel
    ViewModel.js
AjaxDataService.svc
Default.aspx
Default.aspx.cs
Default.js
knockout.js
web.config
```

## AjaxDataService.svc

```cs
<%@ServiceHost language=c# Debug="true" Service="KnockoutDemo.AjaxDataService" %>
```

## AjaxDataService.svc.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace KnockoutDemo
{
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
    AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public class AjaxDataService : IAjaxDataService
  {
    public string GetThatString()
    {
      return "That String!";
    }
    public string TestAjaxCall()
    {
      return "Ajax works!";
    }
  }

  [ServiceContract]
  [ScriptService]
  public interface IAjaxDataService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    string GetThatString();
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string TestAjaxCall();
  }
}
```

## web.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="KnockoutDemo.Services.AjaxDataService"
          behaviorConfiguration="AjaxServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="KnockoutDemo.Services.IAjaxDataService"/>
        <endpoint address=""
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>s
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AjaxServiceBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="returnFaults"
           returnUnknownExceptionsAsFaults="true"/>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this help? [Why can't I access my WCF web service with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328466/why-cant-i-access-my-wcf-web-service-with-javascript/14328818#14328818)

Comment: I don't understand why you can use a contract attribute on a binding and point it to a class instead of an interface.. I tried that, and tried to copy how you say you set up your wcf services for AJAX and I'm still getting a 404 error.

Comment: I didn't use an interface to define a service contract in that example only to keep my answer short. The 404 error means that there isn't an endpoint listening at the url specified in the ajax call. Please double check that your ajax call is using the correct url, something like: "serviceUrl + separator + operationName" => _http://localhost/WebAppName/WcfService.svc/GetThatString

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena see the first code block list of URL's. I've tried that exact URL and others and still get 404'd.

Comment: What happens if you hit F5 (debug) with your WCF service code file open/focused in Visual Studio? Does the WCF service page displays correctly in the browser or you get 404 as well?

Comment: I'm not using visual studio for this. I'm trying to do it at my home PC on Windows 8, using Notepad++.